# AND OR in where with codingniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a problem in using of WHERE functions in codeigniter. 
Suppose we have two array as follow:

```
    $t1=arrray('a','b');
    $t2=array('c','d');
```

I want to do OR elements in array `$t1`, also I want to OR elements in array `$t2` too. then I want to do AND result of two arrays.

for example

```
where (table1.id='a' or table1.id='b') and (table2.id='c' or table2.id='d').
```

how I set that in codeigniter?

Comment: `$this->db->where("(table1.id='a' or table1.id='b') and (table2.id='c' or table2.id='d')");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where("(table1.id='a' OR table1.id='b')");
$this->db->where("(table2.id='c' OR table2.id='d')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$where = "(table1.id='a' OR  table1.id='b') AND (table2.id='c' or table2.id='d')";
    $this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: Can you explain the code in your answer? Two lines of code without any explanation are not consider a proper answer in SO (from review).

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many StackOverflow users are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted, so will not learn from your answer.